# UITableViewCell Repeating images

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to add a favourites images in the table view cell. I am using this code

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"memberCell";
MemberCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSDictionary *item = self.searchList[indexPath.row];

cell.memberFullName.text = [item[@"full_name"] uppercaseString] ;
cell.memberPosition.text =  [item[@"title"] length] < 1 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  item[@"districts"]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", item[@"title"], item[@"districts"]];
cell.memberRoom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rm %@", item[@"room_number"] ];
[cell.memberImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item[@"image_thumb"]]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

if(![item[@"fid"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    [cell.memberFavoriteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite"]];
}
```

The problem i am having is the favourite images are showing on multiple cells even though the condition `if(![item[@"fid"] isEqualToString:@"0"])`  is passed only for **1 cell**, when i do a `NSLog`, the condition is passed once only but the images are displayed is a systematic order (that is each 9th row), when i scroll all the way down and come back the order completely changes and images are shown in different rows. I am not sure what is happening, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dequeue instruction potentially returns an existing instance of cell

try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    MemberCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MemberCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *item = self.searchList[indexPath.row];
    cell.memberFullName.text = [item[@"full_name"] uppercaseString] ;
    cell.memberPosition.text =  [item[@"title"] length] < 1 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  item[@"districts"]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", item[@"title"], item[@"districts"]];
    cell.memberRoom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rm %@", item[@"room_number"] ];
    [cell.memberImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item[@"image_thumb"]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    if(![item[@"fid"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [cell.memberFavoriteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite"]];
    } else {
        [cell.memberFavoriteImage setImage:nil];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    MemberCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MemberCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *item = self.searchList[indexPath.row];
    cell.memberFullName.text = [item[@"full_name"] uppercaseString] ;
    cell.memberPosition.text =  [item[@"title"] length] < 1 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  item[@"districts"]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", item[@"title"], item[@"districts"]];
    cell.memberRoom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rm %@", item[@"room_number"] ];
    [cell.memberImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item[@"image_thumb"]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
    if(![item[@"fid"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [cell.memberFavoriteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite"]];
    }

    return cell;
```